# Using withEnv and withCredentials together

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Suppose you have a scenario where you have a username and password credential that you would like to use as part of populating the (de-facto) standard `http_proxy` environment variable. The first attempt would be something like this:

```
withCredentials([usernameColonPassword(credentialsId:'proxy-credentials', variable:'PROXY_CREDENTIALS')]) {
  def proxyUrl = "https://${env.PROXY_CREDENTIALS}@proxy-endpoint.com:3128"
  withEnv(["http_proxy=${proxyUrl}"]) {
    // Do stuff
  }
}
```

However, while that works, Jenkins flags it as unsafe. This doesn't work either:

```
withCredentials([usernameColonPassword(credentialsId:'proxy-credentials', variable:'PROXY_CREDENTIALS')]) {
  withEnv(['http_proxy=https://${PROXY_CREDENTIALS}@proxy-endpoint.com:3128']) {
    // Do stuff
  }
}
```

This is because there is no "shell expansion" in a `withEnv`, and thus `http_proxy` is set to have a literal `${PROXY_CREDENTIALS}` in it, which is not what we want.

Any ideas on how to set up `http_proxy` safely?

Answer (score -2):

Try this :

```
withCredentials([usernameColonPassword(credentialsId:'proxy-credentials', variable:'PROXY_CREDENTIALS')]) {
  withEnv(["http_proxy=https://$PROXY_CREDENTIALS@proxy-endpoint.com:3128"]) {
    // Do stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: Jenkins will throw a warning about this being unsafe.